# jQuery scroll top fade in

Tags: jquery

Im having trouble animating divs on scroll. The idea is that the divs fade in when 500px from the top of the window, but instead of animating one at a time whats written is animating all divs at once, despite using "this".

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $("div").scrollTop(function(){
      $(this).css({"opacity" : "1" , "transform" : "translateY(0px)" , "-webkit-transform" : "translateY(0px)" , "-webkit-transition" : "1s"});
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
div {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(30px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: It's because you're selecting all divs with `$('div')`. Add a check inside scrollTop to limit the animation to the div you want.

Comment: I want to apply this to a class I can reuse on multiple divs. For example as you scroll down the page each div will animate up when 500px from the top.

Comment: Are the divs stacked on top of each other? Do you want them to appear all at once when scrollTop = 500px?

Comment: Yeah they are a series of stacked divs 100% wide